# Serve anoher server from subdomain

Tags: ubuntu, scrapy, vhosts

on my root server `http://my.root.ip` I have a scrapy server running at `http://my.root.ip:6800`.
I want to make `http://my.root.ip:6800` accessable from a subdomain like `http://scrapy.mydomain.com`.

I know I can setup a vhost file and point the document root to somewhere on my server but now I have a server on a server actually.

```
ServerName scrapy.mydomain.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /path

 <Directory /path>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
 </Directory>
```

How can I do that? Do I have to add something to vhost file?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add an A record to your dns fields.

Here is some more info: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/delegate.html

Also add the subdomain to the htaccess file

```
VirtualHost *:6800 

<VirtualHost *> 
ServerName www.website.com 
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *> 
ServerName scrapy.website.com 
DocumentRoot "/var/www/scrapy" 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: hm, plesk lets me just enter the ip of my server for the A record but not the port